# Are there conditions for which $\int_{a}^{x} O(f(t)) dt = O\left( \int_{a}^{x} f(t)) dt \right)$ (same for derivatives)

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I was wondering if in asymptotics there some conditions for integral/derivatives where I can do something like

$$\int_{a}^{x} O(f(t)) dt = O\left( \int_{a}^{x} f(t)) dt \right)$$

Or something like

$$ \frac{d O(f(x))}{dx} = O\left( \frac{df(x)}{dx} \right)$$

I've been watching some videolectures, and sometimes I just see people using as nothing this stuff, but I wonder more about the conditions that allow to do such calculations.

Answer (score 0):

With $f(t)=\sin t$, $g(t)=1$, we have $f=O(g)$, but not $f'=O(g')$ (as $t\to\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

For the integral, let's try
$$
f(x) = \frac{4}{x^5} - \frac{5}{x^6}
$$
so that
$$
f(x) = O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)
$$
Then compute
$$
\int_1^x f(t)\;dt = \frac{1-x}{x^5} = O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)
$$
and
$$
\int_1^x \frac{1}{t^5}\;dt = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4x^4} = O(1)
$$

The point being that
$$
\frac{4}{x^5} - \frac{5}{x^6}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{x^5}
$$
are asymptotically within a constant factor of each other, but their integrals $\int_1^x$ are not.

So how about saying what you mean by
$$
\int_{a}^{x} O(f(t)) dt = O\left( \int_{a}^{x} f(t)) dt \right)
$$

Comment: I don't understand your question... what can I possibly mean by$$\int_{a}^{x} O(f(t)) dt = O\left( \int_{a}^{x} f(t)) dt \right)$$?

Comment: Let $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ such that for $1 \leq j \leq n$ we have $f_j(x) = O(f(x))$. Define also $F_1(x),\ldots, F_n(x), F(x)$ be the antiderivatives of $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x),f(x)$. Is it true that $F_j(x) = O(F(x))$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$? (that's what I mean), but looking at your answer it doesn't seems generally true.

Comment: @GEdgar I think you want to write $1/x^5 = O(f(x))$ above and leave $f(x) = O(1/x^5)$ out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example where the integral result can fail. Note $|\sin(1/t)| = O(\sin(1/t)$ as $t\to 0.$ But $\int_0^x |\sin(1/t)|\,dt$ is bounded below by a postive constant times $x$ as $x\to 0^+,$ while $\int_0^x \sin(1/t)\,dt = O(x^2).$

If you assume $f\ge 0,$ then no problem like this can arise, and the result is immediate.