# An asymptotic estimation of a summation using Abel summation formula and asymptotics.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, asymptotics

I'm referring to both [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313469/are-there-conditions-for-which-int-ax-oft-dt-o-left-int-ax-f) and [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula). I'd like to asymptotically estimate

$$
S(x) = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq x} \arctan(2^{-j})
$$
as $x \geq 1$ diverges. Applying the Abel summation formula I get

$$
S(x) = [x]\arctan(2^{-x}) + \log 2 \int_{1}^{x} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}} dt.
$$

We have

$$
[x]\arctan(2^{-x}) \leq x2^{-x} \Rightarrow [x]\arctan(2^{-x}) = O(x2^{-x})
$$

we have the integral to estimate (I'll not consider the $\log 2$ constant for now)

$$
I(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}} dt = \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}} dt - \int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}} dt = C - \int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}}dt
$$

the last integral can be bounded by

$$
\int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}}dt \leq \int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{t2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}}dt \leq \int_{x}^{+\infty} t2^{-t}dt.
$$

$$
\frac{[t]2^{-t}}{1+2^{-2t}} = O(t2^{-t})
$$

and it should result in this specific case

$$
\int_{x}^{+\infty} O(t2^{-t}) dt = O\left(\int_{x}^{+\infty} t2^{-t} dt \right) = O(x2^{-x})
$$

therefore I should end up with

$$
I(x) = C + O(x2^{-x})
$$

and my original summation should be

$$
S(x) = C + O(x2^{-x})
$$

Now I'm not sure here... because S(x) is positive, therefore when $x \rightarrow \infty$ the function $h(x) = O(x2^{-x})$ it's bounded by definition of $O(\cdot)$ by some $k x2^{-x}$ thefore we $x$ diverges we have $h(x) \sim x2^{-x}$ and I can therefore infer that

$$
S(x) \sim C + x2^{-x}
$$

I know it's a bit messy, but I'm personally confused for the notation.
Is this stuff right? To me it kinda of make sense, have a look at [this plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qckud3oveb), but still not sure. By the way to $f(x) \sim g(x)$ when $x \rightarrow x_0$ when the limit of the the ratio $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ equals some constant (not necessarily $1$).

**Update** : Following what @Professor Vector suggested

Defining $S$ the limit value, because $S(x)$ converges as $x \rightarrow \infty$ we have

$$
0 \leq E(x) = S - S(x) = \sum_{x < j < \infty} \arctan(2^{-j}) \leq \sum_{x < j < \infty} 2^{-j} = 2^{-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor} = 2^{-\left\{ x \right\}} 2^{-x} \leq 2^{-x}.
$$

therefore we have

$$
0 \leq S - S(x) \leq 2^{-x}
$$

the upper bound tends to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, implying that

$$
S - S(x) \sim 2^{-x} \Rightarrow S(x) = S - 2^{-x} + o(2^{-x})
$$

as $x \rightarrow \infty$ therefore we have $S(x)$ tends to its limit as fast as $2^{-x}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: As far as I can see, this derivation is correct, but why so complicated? You could use the rather obvious $\arctan2^{-j}\le2^{-j}$ to get a stronger estimate.

Comment: Because I'm never sure whether or not asymptotics is preserved under summation etc. But please if you have a faster/better approach, can you please write the answer down?

Comment: Erm... no, sorry, because that would mean to chew something as elementary as $S(x) \le \sum_{1 \leq j \leq x}2^{-j}$ for you, and that would be almost insulting.

Comment: But I'm probably missing something, is the bound you could get using that simple argument tighter than mine? Also what I was trying to find out is how fast does $S(x)$ converge as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: $2^{-x}$ is better than $x\,2^{-x},$ yes (the error term of the series is $\le\sum_{j>x}2^{-j}=2^{-x}$, if $x$ is integer).

Comment: @ProfessorVector, I updated my question, but reading your comment probably I have to rethink about it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Updated again, it should be fine now, is that right?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kpsvjlpcet, this plot convinces me...